# Attempted to rewrite getElementByClassName, running into a recursive snap

Tags: javascript

As the title mentions, I tried rewriting getElementByClassName as a personal exercise, but am running into some unexpected behavior with my recursive return of results.

```
Document.prototype.getElementsByClassNameExercise = function(className, tempElement){
  var currentElement = (tempElement || document),
    children = currentElement.childNodes,
    results = [],
    classes = [];

  // Loop through children of said element
  for(var i =0;i<children.length;i++){    
    if(children[i].className && children[i].className !== '') {
      classes = children[i].className.split(' ');

      // Important to note, forEach is not ie8 safe.
      classes.forEach(function(singleClass){
        if(singleClass === className) {
          results.push(children[i]);
        }
      });
    }
    results.concat(Document.prototype.getElementsByClassNameExercise.call(this,     className, children[i]));
  }

  return results;
}
```

I attempted this on my homepage, and it appears to successfully parse all DOM elements and find the className... but the return/ results.concat(results) step seem to fail. :/

Any takers can see what I am missing? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Your Problem

You're not missing much.

[`concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) returns a new array, as explained in its [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) article:

> **Summary**
>
> Returns a new array comprised of this array joined with other array(s) and/or value(s).
>
> **Description**
>
> [...] concat does not alter this or any of the arrays provided as arguments but instead returns a shallow copy that contains copies of the same elements combined from the original arrays.

In case of doubt, you can also always refer to the [ECMA-262 specs](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) if the MDN isn't enough, section 15.4.4.4:

> When the concat method is called with zero or more arguments item1, item2, etc., it returns an array containing the array elements of the object followed by the array elements of each argument in order.

## Solution

You need to-reassign the results variable.

Change this line:

```
results.concat(Document.prototype.getElementsByClassNameExercise.call(this,     className, children[i]));
```

to:

```
results = results.concat(Document.prototype.getElementsByClassNameExercise.call(this,     className, children[i]));
```

Comment: Wow, that was fast! I have to wait 9 more minutes to click on the check box. I can't believe I missed that, thank you!

Comment: @TheIronDeveloper: you're welcome, glad it helped. In the future, maybe this sort of question is better suited for [CodeReview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), as you weren't really looking for an explanation of a particular problem or technical issue but were trying to get someone to review your code.

Comment: Thank you for both helping me and politely redirecting me. I'll make sure to post code-review related posts in that section instead. :)